# GridView pass parameter in url and use in another page

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm able to pass the parameter in the URL, however, i'm unsure of how to grab that ID on the next page.

I'm using a GridView to pass the parameter onclick, below is the code i'm using.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.color='Black';this.style.cursor='hand';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.color='Black';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "window.navigate('NavigatedPage.aspx?id=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Trim() + "')";
    }
}
```

i need what's after the id=

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the next page, do:

```
 string id =Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Answer (score 2):

I could be mistaken from what your trying to ask, but I think your trying to accertain how to access the query string parameter on a new page. If this is the case then it's

```
Request.QueryString["name"]
```

But remember to check if its got some contents first

What I like to do is

```
string GetQueryStringVarible(string name, string defaultValue)
{
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString[name])
  { 
    return Request.QueryString[name];
  } 
  else 
  {
    return defaultValue;
  }
}
```