# Passing values to another html page based on values in a grid view

Tags: c#, gridview, html

i have a grid view on a web page that consists of a tariff , supplier , term and prices.

in this grid view there will be around 20-30 different tariffs. my aim is to select a tariff and pass through the term and prices into the next web page.

I populate the grid view via a stored proc by passing through meter details.

In new to html so hoping if anyone can point mt in the right direction.

[image]

So the example above i will click the highlighted tariff and on my new web page i can display the term (25) and the rates to the right.

Comment: When you want to redirect to the other page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199433/gridview-pass-parameter-in-url-and-use-in-another-page

Comment: On the click of the highlighted cell.

Comment: So look at the posted link above and replace `e.Row.Attributes["onclick"]` with `e.Row.Cells[2]Attributes["onclick"]...`